# Script isn't served compressed from IIS

Tags: iis, compression, iis-10

I have IIS 10 running on Windows 2016 (I see exactly same behavior on Windows 2019). I enabled static compression. I can see that the browser (Chrome) sends `accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br`. I can even see that a compressed version is generated in `C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\JMSv2\$^_gzip_D^\WEBSITES\JMSV2\MAIN.3616F3D5444DF5AB2F98.JS` (5MB in size). Everything seems to be working properly. However, javascript file comes *uncompressed* -

```
content-length: 38886877  
content-type: application/javascript
```

What am I missing? I saw in one answer that corporate network was stripping headers from response. My server is on AWS and standalone. Dynamic caching is *not* enabled

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it was `hit frequency` that wasn't reached (since I was testing). In order to verify that it is working, the easiest is to set the value of the staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency attribute in the  element as true to disable the "hit frequency" check just for testing purpose
[Using IIS Compression](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/iis-compression/using-iis-compression)